# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) after Migrating to spring boot 3.2;Hibernate 6.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, out-of-memory, many-to-one

if I set @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) it is working. In my case I need EAGER loading. But this leads to the OutOfMemoryError. Even if they increase the in maven memory, it does not work:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how many rows are going to be fetched? Do you need all of these rows?

Comment: for the affected part are just 24 rows.

Comment: @Roni you need to take the dump and analyze the heap memory, don't think 24 rows going to cause `OutOfMemoryError`